# RhoMobile rake Windows Mobile Error

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I am receiving an error message whenever I try to compile a test RhoMobile application developed in RhoStudio. The test application was developed using the instructions provided here:

http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhostudio.tutorial

The compile command issued was:
 rake run:wm 
The error message received at the end of the compile sequence was:

CMD: vcbuild /M4 rhodes.sln "Release|MC3000c50b (ARMV4I)" rake aborted

I am running the application on Windows 7 64 bit, with the compiler configured according to these specifications:

http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/build#build-for-windows-mobile

Would it be possible for somebody to inform me as to why this error message is occuring? Thank you.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to check is your rhobuild.yml file and see if the windows mobile specifics are well configured. Mine for example has this:

> cabwiz: "C:/Program Files/Windows Mobile 6 SDK/Tools/CabWiz"
>      vcbuild: "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/vcpackages/vcbuild.exe"
>      msbuild: "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe"

Also, is there any other message showing a vcBuild error?

I used to have this error for example:

> vcbuild.exe : error VCBLD0007: Could not find project configuration
>   RELEASE|WINDOWS MOBILE 6.5.3 PROFESSIONAL DTK (ARMV4I) to build.

If you haven't already check in the [Rhomobile Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/rhomobile). There are probably similar problems there and can give an extra insight.

Comment: @user1884723 is you solved you problem put this as correct answer.